# J2ee packaging - where should 3rd party libs go?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm working on an older j2ee project.  It runs on JBoss.  It deploys various ears and wars.  It also requires many jar files in the $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib directory. Should those all be moved to the ear and war files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing will work fine, but I usually like to put them in the individual EAR/WAR files.

The biggest reason for that is if you have multiple applications that use the same libraries and want to upgrade to a new version for one app, you can do that without affecting the rest of them.  This of course is especially important if the new version of the library introduces a breaking change that would then have to be fixed in all your applications rather than just the one that needs the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that I have placed the .jar files in $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib, I have ended up regretting it.  Unless it just won't work due to strange dependency problems, it's much better to put them in your ear/war.